# SQL in Google spreadsheets, selecting multiple values of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

I have got a Google sheets table called Purchases with various columns for different items to purchase. The first column is called Status, and it includes values like:

```
Research, Approval, Purchasing, Shipping, Invoicing, Complete.
```

I want to write an SQL statement to retrieve all orders that are not Complete, but I would like to ordered them so that all the Research ones go first, Approvals second, Purchasing third and so on.

My current formula is:

`=QUERY(Purchases;SELECT * WHERE A <> 'Completo';1)`

This retrieves the correct items but they are mixed and not in the order that I want. Can someone help me to do better than this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a custom sorting order by values from a list.

Assuming, your data is in range A:B:

`=QUERY({arrayformula(
  VLOOKUP(A:A,
    {{"Research";"Approval";"Purchasing";"Shipping";"Invoicing"},{1;2;3;4;5}},2,)),
  A:B},
"SELECT Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2 <> 'Complete' and Col2 <> '' order by Col1",1)`

Notes:

- `{{"Research";"Approval";"Purchasing";"Shipping";"Invoicing"},{1;2;3;4;5}}`
  is a list of values for sorting, you may use a range instead.
- Change `A:B` to your `Purchases` range
- Need to use `Col1` notation in a query, because source data will be an array, not range.
- we sort by Col1. This column contains numbers, so the sort is legal.
- You may use `select *`, but it will return the column with numbers: